# Undefined array key PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy corrigiendo una pagina y el problema es que la tabla no imprime o visualiza los datos, me muestra el "Undefined array key "id_nivel_autorizado", este es el codigo, ya intente de todo pero no se soluciona.

```
query1 = "SELECT documento, nombre, seg_nom, apellido, seg_apelli, fecha_regis,id_nivel_auto FROM candidato
              WHERE id_nivel_auto= '1' AND estado='A' AND documento LIKE '%".$q. "%' OR nombre LIKE '%".$q."%' OR seg_nom LIKE '%".$q."%' OR apellido LIKE '%".$q."%' OR seg_apelli LIKE '%".$q."%' LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantidadMostrar)." , ".$CantidadMostrar;
  
   } elseif ($numero>1) { 
    $query1 ="SELECT documento, nombre, seg_nom, apellido, seg_apelli,a.id_nivel_auto, b.nivel_autorizado FROM candidato as a, etapa_formacion as b WHERE estado='A' AND
         a.id_nivel_auto=b.nivel_autorizado  AND MATCH (nombre, seg_nom, apellido, seg_apelli) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
       
  }

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conec, $query1);
}
    
    $salida = "<table style='background-color: white; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;' class='datooos'>
                    <thead style='border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; color: white;'>
                        <tr style='background-color: #ddd;'>
                            <th style='background-color: #0D47A1;border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$no_identificacion."</th>
                            <th style='background-color: #0D47A1;border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$nombres_y_apellidos." </th>
                            <th style='background-color: #0D47A1;border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$etap."</center></th>
                            <th style='background-color: #0D47A1;border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'colspan='2'><center>".$rhi."</center></th>
               <th style='background-color: #0D47A1;border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$informe_psicologico_mi."</th>
                        </tr><br><br>
                    </thead>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ){
        $cedula = $row['documento'];

        /*Codifica datos con base64_encode*/
        $id = base64_encode($cedula); 
        $salida .= "<tr>
                        <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$row['documento']."</td>
                        <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$row['apellido']." ".$row['seg_apelli']." ".$row['nombre']." ".$row['seg_nom']."</td>
                      <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'>".$row['id_nivel_autorizado']."</td>
                        <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'><center><a href='registrar.php?id=$id'><img src='../imagenes/edit.png'</a></center></td>
                        <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'><center><a href='historial.php?id=$id' type='button'><img src='../imagenes/historial.png'></a></center></td>
          
          <td style='border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px 10px;'><center><a href='informe_psicologico_can.php?id=$id'><img src='../imagenes/edit.png'</a></center></td>
          </tr>";
                                        
    }
    $salida.="</table>";
    echo $salida;
```

espero puedan ayudarme, la verdad no encuenro el error

Comment: pero si en tu query dice claramente que se llama `id_nivel_auto` y intentas buscar `id_nivel_autorizado` y el otro campo es `nivel_autorizado` :v

Comment: Se me paso, lo cambie pero sigue sin reconocer la variable

Comment: sigue estando igual en tu pregunta por lo que te recomiendo hacer un `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))` y veas cuales son las keys que recibes y sus respectivos nombres!

Comment: Hay dos consultas en tu código, puede que lo hayas cambiado en una y no en la otra.

Comment: Ya lo cambie y  nada :((

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el `var_dump` que te ha sugerido @Bryro? Por cierto, deberías usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array` dado que estás haciendo una lectura por los nombres de columna, no por los índices numéricos. Prueba a cambiarlo así: **`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ){`** Si aún así no funciona, pon un `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado));` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: array(27) { ["id_candidato"]=> string(3) "284" ["id_nivel_auto"]=> string(2) "10" ["documento"]=> string(10) "1004743741" ["nom_foto"]=> string(16) "Diego Alvear.jpg"

Comment: ["docu_ide"]=> string(12) "SIN REGISTRO" ["docu_lb"]=> string(12) "SIN REGISTRO" ["nombre"]=> string(5) "Diego" ["seg_nom"]=> string(8) "Fernando" ["apellido"]=> string(6) "Alvear"

Comment: ["seg_apelli"]=> string(6) "Trullo" ["libreta_mil"]=> string(1) "0" ["fecha_naci"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["lugar_naci"]=> string(13) "La Uni?n Nari" ["edad"]=> string(2) "23" ["Rh"]=>

Comment: string(12) "SIN REGISTRO" ["celular"]=> string(10) "3203221917" ["telefono"]=> string(1) "0" ["direc_reside"]=> string(40) "Cra. 12 # 20 C - 26 Barrio el Recuerdo. " ["departamento"]=> string(4) "Nari" ["ciudad"]=> string(4) "Nari" ["correo"]=> string(26)

Comment: "alveartrullo148@gmail.com " ["correo_alter"]=> string(0) "" ["estado"]=> string(1) "A" ["usuario_regis"]=> string(1) "0" ["fecha_regis"]=> string(10) "2018-02-05" ["usuario_modif"]=> string(1) "0" ["fecha_modif"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" }

Comment: aparecio eso con el var dum

Comment: nunca use ese caracter :'(  estoy confundida

Comment: ¿Que nunca usaste qué caracter? Si analizas tu var_dump verás que la clave se llama `id_nivel_auto` no se llama `id_nivel_autorizado` si dices que lo has cambiando en todas las consultas, entonces puede que el código anterior se haya quedado en memoria caché o algo así. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código como lo tienes ahora, en la primera consulta, sigues poniendo el nombre de la columna con `id_nivel_auto`